# Symbol to gradient with @generated macro in Julia

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

For reasons of performance, I need gradients and Hessians that perform as fast as user-defined functions ( the ForwardDiff library, for example, makes my code significantly slower). I then tried metaprogramming using the `@generated` macro, testing with a simple function

```
using Calculus
hand_defined_derivative(x) = 2x - sin(x)

symbolic_primal = :( x^2 + cos(x) )
symbolic_derivative = differentiate(symbolic_primal,:x)
@generated functional_derivative(x) = symbolic_derivative
```

This gave me exactly what I wanted:

```
rand_x = rand(10000);
exact_values = hand_defined_derivative.(rand_x)
test_values = functional_derivative.(rand_x)

isequal(exact_values,test_values)        # >> true

@btime hand_defined_derivative.(rand_x); # >> 73.358 μs (5 allocations: 78.27 KiB)
@btime functional_derivative.(rand_x);   # >> 73.456 μs (5 allocations: 78.27 KiB)
```

I now need to generalize this to functions with more arguments. The obvious extrapolation is:

```
symbolic_primal = :( x^2 + cos(x) + y^2  )
symbolic_gradient = differentiate(symbolic_primal,[:x,:y])
```

The `symbolic_gradient` behaves as expected (just as in the 1-dimensional case), but the @generated macro does not respond to multiple dimensions as I believed it would:

```
@generated functional_gradient(x,y) = symbolic_gradient
functional_gradient(1.0,1.0)

>> 2-element Array{Any,1}:
    :(2 * 1 * x ^ (2 - 1) + 1 * -(sin(x)))
    :(2 * 1 * y ^ (2 - 1))
```

That is, it doesn't transform the symbols into generated functions. Is there an easy way to solve this?

*P.S.:* I know I could define the derivatives with respect to each argument as one-dimensional functions and bundle them together into a gradient (that's what I'm currently doing), but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I think you don't need to use `@generated` here: this is a "simple" case of code generation, where I'd argue using `@eval` is simpler and less surprising.

So the 1D case could be rewritten like this:

```julia
julia> using Calculus

julia> symbolic_primal = :( x^2 + cos(x) )
:(x ^ 2 + cos(x))

julia> symbolic_derivative = differentiate(symbolic_primal,:x)
:(2 * 1 * x ^ (2 - 1) + 1 * -(sin(x)))

julia> hand_defined_derivative(x) = 2x - sin(x)
hand_defined_derivative (generic function with 1 method)

# Let's check first what code we'll be evaluating
# (`quote` returns the unevaluated expression passed to it)
julia> quote
           functional_derivative(x) = $symbolic_derivative
       end
quote
    functional_derivative(x) = begin
            2 * 1 * x ^ (2 - 1) + 1 * -(sin(x))
        end
end

# Looks OK => let's evaluate it now
# (since `@eval` is macro, its argument will be left unevaluated
#  => no `quote` here)
julia> @eval begin
           functional_derivative(x) = $symbolic_derivative
       end
functional_derivative (generic function with 1 method)
```

```julia
julia> rand_x = rand(10000);
julia> exact_values = hand_defined_derivative.(rand_x);
julia> test_values = functional_derivative.(rand_x);

julia> @assert isequal(exact_values,test_values)

# Don't forget to interpolate array arguments when using `BenchmarkTools`
julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> @btime hand_defined_derivative.($rand_x);
  104.259 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

julia> @btime functional_derivative.($rand_x);
  104.537 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)
```

Now the 2D case does not work because the output of `differentiate` is an array of expressions (one expression per component), which you need to transform into an expression which builds an array (or a Tuple, for performance) of components. This is `symbolic_gradient_expr` in the example below:

```julia
julia> symbolic_primal = :( x^2 + cos(x) + y^2  )
:(x ^ 2 + cos(x) + y ^ 2)

julia> hand_defined_gradient(x, y) = (2x - sin(x), 2y)
hand_defined_gradient (generic function with 1 method)

# This is a vector of expressions
julia> symbolic_gradient = differentiate(symbolic_primal,[:x,:y])
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 :(2 * 1 * x ^ (2 - 1) + 1 * -(sin(x)))
 :(2 * 1 * y ^ (2 - 1))

# Wrap expressions for all components of the gradient into a single expression
# generating a tuple of them:
julia> symbolic_gradient_expr = Expr(:tuple, symbolic_gradient...)
:((2 * 1 * x ^ (2 - 1) + 1 * -(sin(x)), 2 * 1 * y ^ (2 - 1)))

julia> @eval functional_gradient(x, y) = $symbolic_gradient_expr
functional_gradient (generic function with 1 method)
```

Like in the 1D case, this performs identically to the hand-written version:

```julia
julia> rand_x = rand(10000); rand_y = rand(10000);
julia> exact_values = hand_defined_gradient.(rand_x, rand_y);
julia> test_values = functional_gradient.(rand_x, rand_y);

julia> @assert isequal(exact_values,test_values)

julia> @btime hand_defined_gradient.($rand_x, $rand_y);
  113.182 μs (2 allocations: 156.33 KiB)

julia> @btime functional_gradient.($rand_x, $rand_y);
  112.283 μs (2 allocations: 156.33 KiB)
```

Comment: Was about to say the same. Might be worth adding that `symbolic_antiderivative` is super-confusing here, it's the original function, or "primal" if you need a term.

Comment: Thanks, I entirely agree on the confusion regarding the naming of `symbolic_antiderivative`. I edited to use `primal` as you suggested

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I also changed to `symbolic_primal` to match your answer and because it was obviously a very bad name. A last question from someone not yet very used to Julia is: what is the purpose of the `quote`d piece of code in your first block? You say you're checking something, but I don't get what.

Comment: `quote ... end` is more-or-less `:( ... )`, it makes an `Expr`, usually (as here) with other expressions interpolated into it. Instead of `@eval begin ...` (which quotes the block for you) you could write `eval(quote ...`, passing an expression to a function.